# wxWidgets dark mode on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

According to the release notes for 3.1.3 (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/v3.1.3/docs/changes.txt) dark mode support has been added to wxWidgets for Mojave+.

For the documentation for wxSysColourChanged, it still states that this is for Windows only but I thought the dark mode support for macOS should include this too? Dark mode is only a recent addition to Windows UWP apps and not Win32 (see [dark mode on Windows 10](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=45869) for a discussion of that on the forum).

In any case I cannot get the event to fire, although switching to dark mode does indeed correctly update the GUI elements eg. wxlistctrl and wxbutton without me having to manually enforce colour changes.
I am trying to capture the system colour change event so that I can manually redraw my own "owner-drawn" custom GUI elements correctly dark/light.

I hook up the Bind in the constructor to my event but nothing works:

```
Bind(wxEVT_SYS_COLOUR_CHANGED, &myFrame::OnSystemColourChanged, this);

void myFrame::OnSystemColourChanged(wxSysColourChangedEvent &event)
{
  wxSystemAppearance s = wxSystemSettings::GetAppearance();
  wxString dark = s.IsDark() ? "it's dark" : "it's light";
  wxString m("System colour changed - ");
  m += dark;
  ::wxMessageBox(m);
  event.Skip();
}
```

I have got this open as a query on the forum ([here](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=46558)) and they recommended the mailing list but I notice that wxWidgets questions are quickly addressed on here, particularly by VZ so here's hoping!

Am I missing some method of detecting colour changes?

Comment: Sorry, all I can say is that this is supposed to work and I don't see anything wrong with your code (I assume you build with 10.14 or later SDK as otherwise you wouldn't have dark mode support at all). If you can reproduce the problem in the minimal sample, please open a bug and I'll try to have a look at it the next time I do something under Mac.

Comment: Thanks VZ. I will try and step through what is happening as to why the event handler isn't getting hit.

Answer (score 1):

A lazy but useful method is:

In an OnPaint handler using this method to check the system's dark/light mode.
So that you know how to "Paint" your objects:

```
#include <wx/settings.h>

int main() {
  wxColour color = wxSystemSettingsNative::GetColour(wxSYS_COLOUR_WINDOW);
  // Use the color value to determine whether the system is in day mode or night mode
  return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to get the code to hit. I debugged it by adding a wxApp-level HandleEvent override function to see what events were being handled by the application (yes all events go through here):

```
void myApp::HandleEvent(wxEvtHandler *handler, wxEventFunction func, wxEvent& event) const
{
  wxApp::HandleEvent(handler, func, event);
}
```

wxSysColourChanged events are indeed passing through this.

I managed to get my main frame's handler to hit by hooking up differently. Instead of

```
Bind(wxEVT_SYS_COLOUR_CHANGED, &myFrame::OnSystemColourChanged, this);
```

I used this instead:

```
Bind(wxEVT_SYS_COLOUR_CHANGED, wxSysColourChangedEventHandler(myFrame::OnSystemColourChanged), this);
```

I have no idea why &myFrame::OnSystemColourChanged wouldn't be recognised.
Also, I could not get any message boxes to show up in my event handler. ::wxMessageBox and wxMessageDialog did not show. cout output did show up but no popup GUI dialogs.
I am not going to be showing message boxes in this handler anyway so it isn't a problem but was trying to show a message for debugging/testing purposes.

Comment: that's weird. the cast is only required with the old-style `Connect` call.

Comment: Another idea - is you `Bind()` call inside myFrame constructor or somewhere else?

Comment: This `Bind()` call is inside the myFrame constructor.